# How to change keyboard shortcut for opening Character Viewer on OS X El Capitan

Tags: keyboard, macos, emoji

I can open up the Character Viewer app using the Control-Command-Space keys combination.

I want to change this keyboard shortcut so I can use it for some other action.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 8):

For some reason you can't just disable this shortcut, since it's not listed in the preferences by default.
You have to add a shortcut in System Prefs / Keyboard / Shortcuts named "Emoji & Symbols" and bind it to something else, and it will become available.

[image: unbind emoji]

Comment: I triied your idea. This does not seem to work on my El Capitan.

Comment: How did you try it, and how do you mean it doesn't work? It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I added a shortcut in System Prefs / Keyboard / Shortcuts named "Emoji & Symbols" and bound it to something else, and it didn't become available.

Comment: So when you try to bind a shortcut and press ctrl-cmd-space what happens? Emoji window still pops up? Weird, works perfectly for me on 10.11.5

Comment: Yes. Emoji window still pops up when I bind it, for example, to Command-Alt-G and then press Ctrl-Command-Space. I'm on 10.11.5 as well.

Comment: That's really weird. Are you sure you set it to "All Applications" and not some random one? Either that or you running your UI in some non-English language where this is called something else. 
If you open the Edit menu bar item in any app, the option furthest down, under "Start dictation", for me says "Emoji & Symbols" and then my absurd five-key shortcut. If yours is called something else then obviously you'll have to use that name in settings.

Comment: And if you aren't running your UI in English I would much recommend you do - makes troubleshooting/finding help online so much easier. Haven't used my native tongue with computers since I was 11 or so :)

Comment: In any case, under the Edit menu, below "Start Dictation..." I see "Emoji & Symbols" just like you do. Still, I cannot get your solution to work.

Comment: Added image to clarify. If yours looks exactly the same (except for the specific shortcut shown in 1 & 2)  and you still can't bind ctrl-cmd-space somewhere else (iterm in my case) then idunno what to tell you, sorry.
Except uhh, calm down, how would I even know you're from the middle east  and what would it matter? Assumption was based on your shit not working and that being the only thing I could think of that might explain it, hey.

Comment: No worries mate. All's good. Thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: Not working for me either. It shows the correct shortcut combo on the menu item, but CTRL-COMMAND-SPACE still activates the viewer

Comment: 10.15.7 these steps do not work anymore. You can set the shortcut to whatever you want just as it is shown but macOS will still hog the original shortcut.